# Get string between last dash and last dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Simple question, but i don't know regex that much...

```
http://foo.com/bar/image/abc.jpg
```

How get only the **abc** using regex in javascript?

Comment: What have you tried? http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html Also have you google this? And finally, why does it have to be regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'http://foo.com/bar/image/abc.jpg'.split('/').pop().split('.').shift();
```

Comment: How about `[0]` instead of `shift()` (think multiple `.` characters)

Comment: @ErikE good suggestion - the solution is geared towards the OP's particular problem.  But you are right, if the filename has multiple `.`s then `shift()` would only return the first result.

Comment: That all depends on requirements... if `abc.test.jpg` should return `abc.test` or just `abc`... good points though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:-

```
var url = 'http://foo.com/bar/image/abc.jpg'
var fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

This will give the you "abc". Just a one line code. :)

Comment: This is very 2005. The proper solution is to use the array aggregate functions provided by JS. Things like `split()`, etc

Comment: @Bojangles I disagree. String shredding is a perfectly acceptable solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

How about no regex:

```
var str = "http://foo.com/bar/image/abc.jpg"
str.split("/").slice(-1)[0].split(".")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo here:](http://jsfiddle.net/PCSJx/)

```
var test = "http://foo.com/bar/image/abc.jpg";

var i = test.lastIndexOf("/");
var j = test.lastIndexOf(".");
var str = test.substring(i + 1, j);
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + str + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex version:

```
var result = 'http://foo.com/bar/image/abc.jpg'.match(/[^\/]+(?=\.jpg$)/)[0];
```

explanation for future generations:

the match function return an array of results, but here I am sure that there is only 1 result cause my pattern is anchored to the end of the string, thus i select index [0]

regex:

```
[^\/]+     all that is not a slash one or more times
(?=\.jpg$) is a lookahead that mean: followed by .jpg 
$          stand for the end of the string
```

Comment: If you could explain how you arrived at your answer instead of just giving it would be more applicable to a broader range of people in the future.